# Java - Leitor de Disco (Linux)

Tags: java, linux

Boa noite,

Estava olhando como podemos abrir o leitor de disco no Windows utilizando Java existem vários meios como até mesmo utilizar o vbs.

Queria saber se preciso utilizar alguma biblioteca no Linux ou se posso fazer diretamente por algum comando.

Alguém poderia me orientar?
Obrigado!

Comment: Tente chamar o terminal e executar o comando para ejetar `Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); run.exec("eject -T");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o abrir o drive:

```
try {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("eject cdrom");
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.print(e);
}
```

Para fechar o drive:

```
try {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("eject -t cdrom");
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.print(e);
}
```

Comment: Mais fácil do que no Windows 1000x. Obrigado!